# How can I find a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Nightky Sin just [posted a duplicate](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30200/adc-interrupt-from-nick-gammon) of his [original question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30106/ac-meter-by-adc-timer-interrupt-from-nick-gammon).

I think I remember him asking the same question 2 hours after his first question. That question was most likely closed.

So my question is; how can I verify that this is indeed his third attempt at asking the same question all over again?

(And thus be a bit more harsh in pointing this out in the comments)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the user's ID (click on his/her profile) - yours is 2881. Then do a search in the ordinary search box. You will probably find that the user number is already filled in, in the search box:

[image: Search for posts by a user]

You can then add `deleted:1`/`deleted:yes` to search for deleted posts (**[if you have enough reputation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)**):

```
user:2881 deleted:1
```

Or, you can search for closed questions with `closed:1`/`closed:yes`:

```
user:2881 closed:1
```

You can filter this even more by adding the `is:question` option:

```
user:2881 closed:1 is:question
```

---

A user that keeps asking low-quality questions will probably eventually encounter a question-asking block, as part of Stack Exchange's system for keeping questions of good quality. See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: You didn't bring enough attention to the usefulness of the `deleted`/`closed` options. (**Side note:** only mods/10K+ rep users can see/search for deleted posts.)

Comment: What do you mean by "usefulness"? Can you elaborate on how they could be used?

Comment: I don't seem to have enough reputation to search for deleted posts (except my own). `closed:1` I can do. Nice to know SE will limit questions eventually. I guess I have to earn another 3879 points (-;

Comment: @Gerben I was wrong about the 10K+; it's 10K on a graduated site. Here, it's 2K, so you *should* already be able to do so (if I'm reading the docs right)...

Comment: @NickGammon I edited your answer to reflect what I meant. Feel free to roll back/modify my edit, but I felt like it expanded the answer's usefulness without changing the meaning.